# Running a VPN client on Windows 10, how do I manually add a route to the routing table so that I will always be able to connect to a PC on my network?

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, routing, cisco-anyconnect

I feel like this should be possible!!!  But I don't know why it's not working.  Here are some examples of what I've tried:

route -p add 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.252.0 192.168.0.1

route -p add 192.168.0.1 MASK 255.255.252.0 192.168.0.1

route -p add 192.168.0.21 MASK 255.255.252.0 192.168.0.1

route /p add 192.168.0.21 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1 METRIC 1 IF 2

route /p add 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 METRIC 1 IF 2

FYI, the format for the command is:
route [/f] [/p] [ [] [mask ] [] [metric ]] [if ]]

Comment: what VPN client are you using? some allow you to specify routes that are added as the virtual interface comes up.  it would be dangerous to have routes that specify an exit interface  that doesn't exist, so its best to let the VPNclient application handle adding and removing the new routes. additionally many vpn clients support split tunneling, which is really the thing you are looking for, as it will just pass traffic for the lan to the physical nic instead of the virtual interface.

Comment: @FrankThomas, Cisco AnyConnect (of course :-D ).  Yes, I think without being able to control split-tunneling I can't do what I want to do, and the admins are all-powerful and do not bestow that ability on me.

Answer (score 1):

Running a vpn from your desktop means that all network packets get routed via the vpn. If you want to access the local network you need to implicitly allow local network access from within the vpn software. setting a route within windows won't work as the vpn is handling the data packets to the network.

in wireguard this is easy, you can edit the tunnel and there's a checkbox you can unset to allow local traffic, not sure which vpn you use though.

[image: see pic]

Comment: note that the setting you indicate (the kill-switch) is about much more than just bypassing the VPN for LAN addresses. Kill-switches are designed to prevent you from sending traffic in the clear to the Internet. its a side-effect that it also allows LAN communication. instead you should probably look for a client that supports split tunneling.